# ngForm is invalid before model update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

In my application I `$watch` if the form is valid before doing some stuff. The problem is that ngForm won't compile `models` before I use it.

Exemple : http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7dL67Fn7SaSEkjiFf2q?p=preview

**JS**

```
  $scope.results = [];
  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.testForm.$valid;
  },
    function( valid ) {
      $scope.results.push( valid );
    }
  )
```

**HTML**

```
<ng-form name="testForm" ng-init="test = 1">
  <input ng-model="test" required>
</ng-form>

<p ng-repeat="result in results track by $index" ng-class="{'false': !result, 'true': result}">{{ result }}</p>
```

**Results :**

```
false // Wrong
true
```

The form shouldn't be invalid at first because `$scope.test` is set to 1.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)**:

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener `fn` is called asynchronously (via `$evalAsync`) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of `watchExpression` didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener `fn`, you can compare the `newVal` and `oldVal`. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization.

---

It (almost always) makes sense to ignore this first call using a check:

```
$scope.$watch('testForm.$valid', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue === oldValue) { return; }
    $scope.results.push(newValue);
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UDPcJQtQcXaFnJKmuuoM?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if correctly understand, but it could be that the first time AngularJS checks,

```
$scope.results = [];
```

is empty, therefore result evaluating to false before you push anything in it.

If you start with an non-empty result, say:

```
$scope.results = [1];
```

First evaluation is truey.

I don't think $watch is the proper method. I think your issue has to do with how $watch works, and the digest cycle of Angular.

Comment: The form shouldn't be invalid at first because `$scope.test` is set to 1.

Comment: OK, sorry for my comment about $watch, but like ExpertSystem says, falsey on first $digest pass is "normal" behaviour from Angular.